# Unparseable date: " 2014-05-22 09:09:04.145

Tags: java, date, datetime

This may be an extremely simple typo that I have in my code, but I just can't make it work no matter what I do.

I have the following code:

```
 String date="2014-05-22";
 String time="09:09:04.145"

 String dateAndTime=date.concat(" "+ time);

 DateFormat convertDate=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:SSSZ");
 Date dateOfMeasurement=convertDate.parse(dateAndTime);
```

I have tried using `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:SSSZ` and `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS` for the formatting, but nothing works.

What am I doing wrong?
 Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 DateFormat convertDate=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
 Date dateOfMeasurement=convertDate.parse(dateAndTime);
```

Comment: Please read the full question. I have already tried the solution you suggested.
Thank you.

Comment: Spotted the extremely silly mistake I made, working late hours today. Have copied and indeed, it worked as expected, thank you so much.

Comment: This code only makes sense if those input strings were intended to represent a moment in UTC time zone.

Answer (score 2):

## java.time

You are using troublesome old legacy date-time classes now supplanted by the java.time classes.

## ISO 8601

Your inputs happen to comply with [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. The java.time classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating Strings that represent date-time values. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2014-05-22" );
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse( "09:09:04.145" );
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of( ld , lt );
```

## Time zones

A `LocalDateTime` has no concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. So it does *not* represent a moment on the timeline.

For an actual moment, assign a time zone. Perhaps you intended the inputs to represent a moment in UTC.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC );
```

Or perhaps you know from the context that another particular time zone was intended.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z );
```

## Strings

The format you were attempting to assemble is also defined by the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. Simply call `toString` to generate such a value.

An `Instant` is a basic building-block class in java.time, representing a moment on the timeline in UTC with a resolution up to nanoseconds.

```
String output = zdt.toInstant().toString(); // 2016-09-08T02:46:15Z
```

The `ZonedDateTime` extends standard format by wisely appending the name of the time zone in square brackets.

```
String output = zdt.toString();  // 2016-09-07T23:46:15-03:00[America/Montreal]
```